# Group by ID having a count > X where Date > X

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to query a database and return a list of all ids that occur more than five times between a given date and now.

The following code is my attempt that produces an error.

```
Select id, res_date, count(id) as res_count
from reservations 
Where cancel = 0 and seated = 1 and id <> 0
group by id 
Having COUNT(id) >= 5 and res_date > 5/1/18
```

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to filter *before* the aggregation:

```
Select id, count(id) as res_count
from reservations 
Where cancel = 0 and seated = 1 and id <> 0 and
      res_date >= '2018-05-01'
group by id 
Having count(*) >= 5;
```